# Javascript innerHTML turns PHP scripts into comments on AJAX Response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

When I send request to php page with ajax and I return something with ECHO including php tags it turns it into comments on frontend
eg. `$html = "<?php echo 'php here'; ?>"    echo $html` then when I go to innerHTML in JS and say `document.getElementById('el').innerHTML = response;` it turns into comment and shows it like this in browser `<!--?php echo 'php here'; ?-->`

This is the form.

```
           <form method="POST" id="sortiraj-forma">
                <fieldset>
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="sortiraj-select">Sortiraj po</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="sortiraj-select">
                        <option value="cena">Cena</option>
                        <option value="naziv">Naziv</option>
                    </select>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" value="sortiraj" class="btn btn-primary">Sortiraj</button>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
```

This is jquery sending ajax requiest to sortiraj.php

```
    const form = document.getElementById('sortiraj-forma');
const select = document.getElementById('sortiraj-select');


form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    let izbor = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;

    $.ajax({
        url: 'sortiraj.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            vrstaSorta: izbor
        },
        success: (response) => {
            console.log(response)
            document.getElementById('knjige-row-container').innerHTML = response;
        }
    });
});
```

This is sortiraj.php which returns some php code

```
if($_POST['vrstaSorta'] == 'cena'){
        $knjige = Knjiga::sortirajPoCeni();

        $html = "<?php echo 'PHP HERE'; ?>"

        echo $html;
    }
```

Comment: Javascript (your browser) cannot execute php.

Comment: Is there any workaround?

Comment: Perform your php logic on the server, and return the result.  PHP is a server language.  It has to run on the server.

Comment: Just write `$html = "PHP HERE";`